# How do I assign a static file to an initial forms.FileField?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to initialise a django form FileField with a file from my static directories.  I am using a `ClearableFleInput` widget for the field

```
data_file = forms.FileField(
    #validators=FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['xlsx','csv']),
    label = "Timeseries Data File",
    widget=forms.ClearableFileInput()
)
```

Within the view I'm trying to set the initial form data as follows:

```
initial_data['data_file'] = open(settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/path/to/data_file.csv','r+')
ctx['form'] = EntryForm(initial=initial_data)
return ctx
```

All my other initial data items load but not the filefield.  Can I do this and if so, how?

Comment: is this field associated with a model?

Comment: No, no model association